# position of navbars after resizing bootstrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am kind of new to bootstrap 4.I have a quick how can I control the position of nav bar items in boostrap4 after resizing the window. [image: image before resizing]

I would like to keep the position of cart and logIn the same as before resizing.
[image: image after resizing]
Also, I would like to change the search bar to a dropdown if the srceen is resized and when pressing the dropdown I would like the search bar to be all over the screen something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the last items at the right end you need to separate them into a new .navbar-nav element:

```
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Cart</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Then you need to apply the class mr-auto to the previous element to make it push these to the right. Here is a template that does what you seem to want:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar"
    aria-controls="mainNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavbar">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 mr-auto">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="First name" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-dark my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Dark</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Cart</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

This will be responsive and collapse as you need it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but if you actually keep resizing the screen. Login and cart will be on top of each other which not something I want

Comment: Well since you don't want these two items to be collapsed, you will have to decide what to do with them. The flex-grid will reflow them automatically by default. Feel free to post a question about it, but I've answered your original question.